# How to use copyWith() for nested objects

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a company which can contain multiple customers and therefore is nested.
The company class as well as the customer class contain both `copyWith()` functions.

I realized that if I copy a company object with the `copyWith()` function that the customer list is NOT copied as well and still references the original customer list.

Later in the code, it is possible to accidentally change the original customer list.

**How do I write a `copyWith()` function that copies the company AND the nested customers as well?**

```dart
class Company {
  final String name;
  final List<Customer> customers;

  const Company({required this.name, required this.customers});

  Company copyWith({
    String? name,
    List<Customer>? customers,
  }) {
    return Company(
      name: name ?? this.name,
      customers: customers ?? this.customers,
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
class Customer {
  final String name;

  const Customer({required this.name});

  Customer copyWith({
    String? name,
  }) {
    return Customer(
      name: name ?? this.name,
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
void main() {
  Company company = Company(name: 'Company', customers: [
    Customer(name: 'Customer 1'),
    Customer(name: 'Customer 2'),
  ]);

  Company companyCopy = company.copyWith(name: "Company 2");

  print(company.customers[0].name);
  print(companyCopy.customers[0].name);

  List<Customer> customers = companyCopy.customers;
  customers[0] = Customer(name: "Customer 3");

  /// Here I only wanted to change the companyCopy but... 
  companyCopy = companyCopy.copyWith(customers: customers);

  print(companyCopy.customers[0].name);
  /// ... the original company changes as well! 
  print(company.customers[0].name);

}
```

**Output:**

```
Customer 1
Customer 1
Customer 3
Customer 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Company {
  final String name;
  final List<Customer> customers;

  const Company({required this.name, required this.customers});

  Company copyWith({
    String? name,
    List<Customer>? customers,
  }) {
    return Company(
      name: name ?? this.name,
      customers: List.from(customers ?? this.customers),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If the answer is correct, please check it

Comment: This works, thanks! I will check as soon as possible. 
 Is nesting classes containing `copyWith()` functions not considered best practice? I use the plugin "Dart Data Class" which generates copyWith functions automatically, but it does not consider nesting.